# Fourier-Transforming the Schrödinger Equation in order to solve it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

In Quantum all time favourites equation is given by: $$-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2\,m}\,{\partial_{x}}^2\psi(x,t) = i\,\hbar\,\partial_t\,\psi(x,t)$$

> What happens if you were to apply a Fourier-Transform on this thing in $k$-space?

To cut a long story short: The solution of the Schrödinger equation is generally given by wave-packets:

$$\psi(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\psi}(k)\,e^{\displaystyle i\,k- \omega(k)\,t}\,\mathrm{dk} \quad \text{with dispersion} \quad \omega(k) = \dfrac{\hbar\,k^2}{2\,m}$$

where in my own words $\hat{\psi}(k)$ is the F-T of a given wave-packet at time $\displaystyle t = 0 \quad \hat{\psi}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi(x,0)\,e^{\displaystyle i\,k\,x}\,\mathrm{dx}$

Thus what we are doing is calculating how a given wave-packet $\psi(x,0)$ propagades in time $\psi(x,t)$, right?

---

> **Now our task is** to get this result by applying a F-T to the very first equation and get an ODE for $\hat{\psi}(k,t)$ $\underline{\text{We are supposed to derive the general solution out of that.}}$

Problem is, I don't see how this leads to wave-packets: after performing I merely get:

$$\mathcal{F}\left(- \dfrac{\hbar^2}{2\,m}\,{\partial_{x}}^2\psi(x,t) = i\,\hbar\,\partial_t\,\psi(x,t)\right) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad k^2\,\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2\,m}\,\hat{\psi}(k,t) = \mathcal{F}\left(i\,\hbar\,\partial_t\,\psi(x,t)\right)$$

Next task would be solving the ODE for $\hat\psi(k,t)$ and get the original function $\psi(x,t)$ by inverse F-T.

However how is this related to the solution of wave-packets that I presented above?

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question, but think about how to write $\mathcal F (\partial_t \psi)$ in terms of $\partial _t$ and $\hat \psi$. This leads to a differential equation for $\hat \psi$ . Solve it and then use the inverse Fourier transform to obtain an expression for $\psi$.

Comment: Like that? $$k^2\,\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2\,m}\,\hat{\psi}(k,t) = i\,\hbar,\hat{\psi}'(k,t)$$

Thus solving this leads to $$\hat{\psi} = C\,e^{\displaystyle t\,i\,\dfrac{k^2\,h}{2\,m}}$$

Where $C$ probably can be identified with $\psi(x,0)$ and inverse Fourier-Transforming should be leading to the sought expression.

Comment: Almost, by evaluating your last expression at $t= 0$, you have $\hat\psi(k,0) = C$, which is the Fourier transform of $\psi(x,0)$